# Soundcloud API Get current track name without widget

Tags: soundcloud

Is it possible via the SoundCloud API to get the current playing trackname ? Via the widget it's ok but it will be better (UX point of view) if I could without.

I found nobody mention it, if you have an idea, you're welcome !

Thx

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently looking to do the same thing. Seems that the only way to do it via the API is to use what they call "activities" : https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#activities

So you can have a list of all activities made by a user, which includes the listening of a track. But I assume the activity will appear in the list only once the music has been played, not while the music plays.
Has anyone already used that functionnality ?

Regards,
Seb

Comment: I worked with activities, it give you the likes, the repost, or everything that happen in your stream. But it's not realtime.

Comment: My idea is to listen the player in a tab, to display the new song that i'm listening to in another tab, the current tab.

Comment: I know this post was 8 years ago, but have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I coded this litlle script that bind DOM's updates but it's very tricky.

```
// Bind new song on the soundcloud player    
$('.playbackSoundBadge').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(e){
  track_info = e.target;

  if(track_info.className.indexOf('sc-media-image') > -1){
    thumb = track_info.querySelector('span');
    if(thumb != null){
      splitted_url = track_info.href.split(/\//);

      playing.artist = splitted_url[3];
      playing.trackname = splitted_url[4];
      thumb = track_info.querySelector('span');
      playing.thumbnail = standardizeThumb(thumb.style.backgroundImage);

      toaster(playing);
    }
  }
});


// Toast factory
function toaster(playing){
  // Is there already a toast ?
  toast = document.getElementById('sc-toast');
  if(toast == null){
    toast = document.createElement('div');
    toast.id = 'sc-toast';
    document.body.appendChild(toast);
  }else{
    toast.innerHTML = '';
  }



// Build our toast
  thumb = document.createElement('img');
  thumb.src = playing.thumbnail;
  toast.appendChild(thumb);

  wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  wrapper.className = 'wrapper-text';

  playing.artist = standardizeString(playing.artist);
  playing.trackname = standardizeString(playing.trackname);
  artist = document.createElement('h1');
  artist.innerHTML = playing.artist;
  trackname = document.createElement('h2');
  trackname.innerHTML = playing.trackname;
  wrapper.appendChild(artist);
  wrapper.appendChild(trackname);  

  toast.appendChild(wrapper);
}
```